# Change data on UI without refresh

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

how do I change some data on UI without refreshing the screen in a web app using node js?
I need to change only a few things on the screen. And one more doubt is how the data update on screen whenever the data on the database changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have any code here, so I can't give you the exact answer for your situation. And You have not told me how you want it to not 'refresh' e.g a button click or something like that.

In your case my best tip would be to check out Socket.io, socket.io is a framework in Nodejs that can help you interact with WebSockets. A WebSocket is a direct connection between the client and server and does not require a trigger on the client. Instead of working around it by fetching data every couple of seconds in the app. Jeff from fireship has done a better explanation of this topic you can watch his video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1BfCnjr_Vjg

Official socket.io documentation: https://socket.io/docs/v4/

Useful resources:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZKEqqIO7n-k

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tVUE_JiPU-k

Hope this helps!

Comment: No worries! maybe I can help you implement it for you on github if you would like

Answer (score -2):

You can use JavaScript by a method called (`setTimeout`) By this method you can changes UI by a particular time

Comment: but how do I know the data is updated on db?

Comment: What kind of data are you saving while changeing the Ui